# Mode mappings conflict between method and type level

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, view, controller

I have this problem with my controller.
The log says:"Mode mapping conflict between method and type level: [/fotoProfiloUtente.do] versus [VIEW]. I can't move the method to another controller, i've to use this one. This problem is driving me crazy, i've tried to study Spring MVC or searching on stackoverflow but i didn't find a solution.

This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
@Controller
public class ProfiloController extends SDAPortletController {
    public Log log = SDALogger.getLogger(getClass());
    private static final String VIEW_PAGE = "Profilo";
    private static final String UTENTE_VUOTO = "utenteVuoto.jpg";

    @RequestMapping
    public ModelAndView doView(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response) throws Exception {
        log.debug("Ok passato da doView");
        ModelAndView page = new ModelAndView(VIEW_PAGE);

        List<Opzione> direzione = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Opzione> ruolo = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Opzione> unita = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Opzione> struttura = new ArrayList<>();

        // TODO
        /* Fare lettura da DB */
        direzione.add(Opzione.builder().valore("d1").descrizione("Direzione 1").build());
        direzione.add(Opzione.builder().valore("d2").descrizione("Direzione 2").build());

        ruolo.add(Opzione.builder().valore("r1").descrizione("Ruolo 1").build());
        ruolo.add(Opzione.builder().valore("r2").descrizione("Ruolo 2").build());

        unita.add(Opzione.builder().valore("u1").descrizione("Unita 1").build());
        unita.add(Opzione.builder().valore("u2").descrizione("Unita 2").build());

        struttura.add(Opzione.builder().valore("s1").descrizione("Struttura 1").build());
        struttura.add(Opzione.builder().valore("s2").descrizione("Struttura 2").build());

        page.addObject("elencoDirezione", direzione);
        page.addObject("elencoRuolo", ruolo);
        page.addObject("elencoUnita", unita);
        page.addObject("elencoStruttura", struttura);

        Contatto c;
        c = Contatto.builder()
                .nome("Alessandro")
                .cognome("Nardelli")
                .dataNascita("24/04/1975")
                .mansione("Ingegnere")
                .sigla("xxx")
                .referente("Mario Rossi")
                .telefonoAziendale("063424234")
                .brevi("1414")
                .lineaPrivata("06234243")
                .privati("33322342342")
                .cellulare("324832849")
                .email("alenar@email.it")
                .fax("no")
                .società("IBM")
                .sede("Roma Sede via degli Arcelli")
                .tipoStruttura("Struttura sede")
                .fornitore("xxxxx")
                .via("Via degli Arcelli")
                .responsabile("Mario Bianchi")
                .servizio("Soluzioni di business")
                .unità("xxxx")
                .piano("Piano 2 Stanza 5A")
                .build();
        page.addObject("c", c);

        return page;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/fotoProfiloUtente.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getFotoProfiloUtente(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        ServletContext servletContext = request.getServletContext();
        IUser<IntrasdaUser> utenteAttuale = getUtente();
        IntrasdaUser utenteAttualeConcreto = utenteAttuale.getConcreteUser();
        byte[] immagineProfilo = utenteAttualeConcreto.getImmagineProfilo();
        InputStream in = null;
        if (immagineProfilo==null){
            in = servletContext.getResourceAsStream(UTENTE_VUOTO);
        } else {
            in = new ByteArrayInputStream(immagineProfilo);
        }
        response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
        IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me resolving this issue?